# After setting a value of datepicker, it screws up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="sandbox-container">
  <div class="datepicker"></div>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({});
```

So far so good, looks like this: [image: screenshot]

But as soon as I put a date:

```
$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

The result is:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I should have done this:

```
<div id="datepicker1" class="datepicker"></div>
```

and that:

```
$('#datepicker1').datepicker({});
```

immediatly works.

(facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).setDate(new Date());
```

Comment: `new Date()` does **not** return a string unless cast, but a `Date` object. And according to [the datepicker documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate), a `Date` object is a perfectly valid argument.

Comment: I did: dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd" and still no fix

Comment: Are u calling the datepicker twice

Comment: @ShintuJoseph i that a question? Yepp

Comment: Calling it twice will reinitialise the element and append a new widget